# Who is the oldest mutant (in-universe) in marvel universe?

Tags: marvel, mutant

I have been researching on the subject and I have some doubts with who can be considered the oldest mutant.

At first I thought it was Apocalypse (En Sabah Nur), but when I started looking for information i found others pretendent such as:

- Namor
- Exodus
- Romulus

**[Q]** Do you know which of these (or other one) could be the oldest?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm going to assume you mean the oldest character in-universe.  I believe this is [Selene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selene_(comics)).  To quote the Wikipedia:

> Selene was born over 17,000 years ago somewhere in what is now Central Europe, "after the Oceans swallowed Atlantis and before the rise of the Aryas".

She is Conan the Barbarian era, so before recorded history.

Of those you list, [Namor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namor) was the first to appear out-of-universe but was born in the 20th century.  [Exodus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exodus_(comics)) was born in 12th century France.  [Romulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romulus_(comics)) is unknown, I think.
Another good possibility is [Saul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saul_(comics)) who told Apocalypse that he was older.

Comment: So Selen and Saul are older than Apocalypse? thanks for this good answer.

Comment: I think this is one of those things that will constantly be changing.  New writers, new ideas.  They'll pick or make someone and make them older.  Reading the Romulus entry, it could be him since it mentions showing him in "prehistory".

Answer (score -1):

Well, in the 'X-Men: Apocalypse' film, I think Apocalypse spoke of being present at the beginning of time. At the very least, he was present when the first humans appeared (if we take him at his word).

Also, he was the first mutant. So, surely that would make him the oldest.